# What is the unit used in OpenPyXL for column width?

Tags: python, openpyxl

The [Units documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.units.html) didn't answer my question.

Apparently it is based on OOXML measurements, but I'm not sure because the measurement of row height and column width is not the same, and the link above says: `"The main unit in OOXML is a twentieth of a point."`. So that can't be true. I tried to shoot some numbers and see with LibreOffice Calc but nothing fits:

```py
self.worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 60
self.worksheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 4
```

I found that the rows are in points, but column width gives:

```
pt 333.35
pc 27.78 
4.63 "
cm 11.76
```

Comment: The specification has this to say: "Column width measured as the number of characters of the maximum digit width of the numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 as rendered in the normal style's font. There are 4 pixels of margin padding (two on each side), plus 1 pixel padding for the gridlines.", ie. it's up to the application

Comment: Have u solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

1 unit = 7 pixels. What's the logic? I don't know.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to contain an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

It can depend on the default system font, so there is no definitive answer.  You'll have to find empirical values for your application and device.

I've experimentally found the fudge factor values below worked well for me.

```
WIDTH_FUDGE = (1/7)
HEIGHT_FUDGE = (3/4)
```

Multiply what you would expect the cell width and height values to be **in pixels** by these fudge factors to get the Excel units.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, I'm trying to solve this problem and got fudges like:

```py
HEIGHT_FUDGE = 72/96 = 3/4 # 96 is my screen dpi, 72 is a standart dpi

# my screen resolution is 1366*768
# 95.25 value was found here https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/units.html
WIDTH_FUDGE = 768/1366*(1 - 72/95.25)
```